# При нажатии сохранить фотографию

Tags: jquery

Что написать нужно что бы при нажатии на ссылку шло сохранения какой либо картинки. Как [например тут](https://dikart.ru/catalog/smooth-rods/Gladkotyanutyy_karniz_Kt_283_94Hx91mm/#content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В современных браузерах можно использовать атрибут **download**:

```
function save() {
    var gh = $('#image_id').attr('src');
    var a  = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = gh;
    a.download = 'image.png';
    a.click()
}
```

Думаю создать нечто подобное, используя этот код не составит труда, если Вы более-менее разбираетесь в том, что делаете, если нет - пожалуй Вам нужно будет больше позаниматься улучшением своих знаний...